Literature Request: The derived category is Krull-Schmidt
I am looking for literature where it is proven that the derived category of bounded complexes over a finite-dimensional algebra is Krull-Schmidt. I found this question
Literature request: $K^b(\text{proj} A)$ Krull-Schmidt for $\text{gl dim}A = \infty$ and general results about its Grothendieck group
But no one provides the requested literature. Please, I wonder if someone has a clue.

I do not know a source showing this directly, but you can get it by combining two sources.
Let us write $k$ for the base field. By a theorem of Balmer and Schlichting (Thm. 2.8 here), the category $K^b(\operatorname{proj} A)$ is idempotent complete (or pseudo-abelian).
In addition, $K^b(\operatorname{proj} A)$ is a $k$-category in which all $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets are finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces.
Any additive $k$-category satisfying these two conditions (idempotent complete with finite-dimensional $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets) is a Krull-Schmidt category.
This is shown, for example, in Scharlau's "Quadratic and Hermitian Forms", Chapter 11, Thm. 10.4 and Cor. 11.3. (Cor. 11.3 is stated for hermitian $k$-categories, but the hermitian structure is not necessary for applying 10.4.)
Scharlau's Thm. 10.4 also appears in the more natural source "Algebraic $K$-Theory" by Bass as I, Thm. 3.6, so you can alternatively cite this source. However, checking the assumptions amounts to citing Cor. 11.3 in Scharlau.
